# bluetooth keyboard not in keyboard preferences

Tags: keyboard, macos, bluetooth, microsoft

I have a Microsoft Surface Ergonomic keyboard and a 2016 touchbar MBP running macOS 10.12 (Sierra). The keyboard is connected to the MBP (I can type) but it doesn't show up in keyboard preferences (so I can't remap keys).

How can I get the keyboard to show up to show up in keyboard preferences? How can I remap the keys to be:

- Windows -> Alt
- Alt -> Command
- Caps lock -> Control or Escape.

I'm aware of [karabiner](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/) but am frustrated that is keyboard isn't showing up.

Comment: I landed this page while I'm looking for the issue about the surface ergonomics keyboard with my macbookpro touchbar.
I have the same problem with Mystic, but it's acceptable for me.
However, the bluetooth connection is often disconnected, more than 10 times a day.
Any one has the same issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It doesn't show up for me either on 10.12.2.

[Karabiner Elements](https://github.com/tekezo/Karabiner-Elements) is working great for me.

Comment: Thanks, that worked for me. So sad that the built in pref panel doesn't work automatically.